# Integrating shapefile into Maps.me?

Tags: shapefile, integration, maps.me

I'd just like to add some GIS layers, such as shapefiles in the [Maps.me](https://maps.me/) app.

Has someone already done it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. The only overlay you can get in Maps.me is the bookmarks (points) via a KML. Convert a shp of points to kml using GDAL or QGIS (if using Open Source tools) and follow the recipe from support page https://support.maps.me/hc/en-us/articles/207895029-How-to-import-bookmarks-

For lines, although I did not see a mention in the doc, you should also open the KML with lines. I was able to see the lines using the same process as the bookmarks tutorial using my own device. For polygons, it does not seem to work.

If you want overlay layers, you may look at Geopaparazzi, another application ([a presentation](https://fr.slideshare.net/silli/foss4g2018-presentation-of-the-app-geopaparazzi/14))

Comment: OK, so it is not possible to integrate line and polygon objects. I'll limit myself to points. Thanks for sharing the information all the same.

Comment: Tested with lines and works. For polygons, fails (or I missed something). Edited my answer

Comment: Well that's great, there's just one thing, in which CRS the coordinates must be given ? Because I imagine there is no such thing as OTF reprojection in the app. It is perhaps WGS84 ?

Comment: Well seems to be Pseudo-Mercator 3857.

Comment: Can't be Pseudo-Mercator 3857. KML is only WGS 84 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language#Geodetic_reference_systems_in_KML
FYI, my tests has been done with WGS 84

Answer (score 0):

A late answer (just dscovered this Maps.me StackExchange whilst looking for help myself!). I have had success  uploading shp polygons to maps.me if you first convert the polygon into a multilinestring (I do this in R, but assume there are methods in QGIS), then convert to a .kml

This method done not work well for me (I do not know why) when the multilinestring derives from a multipolygon or complex polygon (e.g. multiple polygons with shared boundaries). Maps.me then uploads the file and correct polygon(s), but adds some extra lines, linking nodes, that were not in the original shp.